# Problem while parsing values of multiple elements with same name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xml-parsing, openxml

I am trying to parse values of multiple elements with the same name. On parsing, it parses only the value of the first element instead of all the values.

Below is what I did to retrieve:

```
DECLARE @DocHandle int  
DECLARE @XmlDocument Varchar(Max) 
SET @XmlDocument = '<Root>
      <Email>test123@gmail.com</Email>
      <Email>test234@gmail.com</Email>
    </Root>'
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @XmlDocument

SELECT Email FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle, '/Root',2) WITH (Email varchar(100))
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle
```

The expected result is:

```
test123@gmail.com
test234@gmail.com
```

The actual result that I get is:

```
test123@gmail.com
```

Comment: Try `SELECT text FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle, '/Root/Email/text()')` and see if it works.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much.
I've been struggling to find out how to solve this. 
Thank you :)